# What was the purpose of the Apple /// interlace mode?

Tags: video, apple-iii

I know that a video interlace mode was available on the Apple /// prototype and eventually on the Apple ///+, but I haven't seen anything that says what it was for. Did it provide a higher resolution mode or was it simply to fill in the horizontal raster gaps?

Comment: Any different from the interlace modes on other systems, retro and latter-day?

Comment: Use a TV as a monitor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Apple III Plus Owner's Guide](https://archive.org/details/Apple_III_Plus_Owners_Guide_1982_Apple_Computer/), the interlace mode is called "[text interlace](https://archive.org/details/Apple_III_Plus_Owners_Guide_1982_Apple_Computer/page/n239)":

> **text interlace** a Feature of the Apple III console that, when activated, increases the resolution of text characters on the display screen.

[Page 39](https://archive.org/details/Apple_III_Plus_Owners_Guide_1982_Apple_Computer/page/n57) provides a little more detail:

[image: The Apple III has text interlace, a function that allows you to turn on a second picture, or matrix of dots, which is in computer memory. When you turn on text interlace, the two identical sets of dots merge, creating a grid of 384 lines of 560 dots per line. The two sets of dots that make up the character *A* merge together, or interlace, to form a more crisply defined character.]

So "text interlace" is simply a mode designed to enhance the appearance of text characters on the screen, without using any additional video memory, or even character ROM! It achieves this by switching from a progressive (non-interlaced) resolution of 560×192 pixels to an interlaced resolution of 560×384 pixels and doubling each row of pixels to stretch each 7×8 character into a 7×16 matrix. But [note](https://archive.org/details/Apple_III_Plus_Owners_Guide_1982_Apple_Computer/page/n59):

> Text interlace works best with green-phosphor and other long-persistence video displays. If you have a black-and-white or color display, text interlace may make the picture flicker.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't sound as though any consideration was given to enlarging the font ROM, tying one extra address bit to the interlace enable/disable control, and the other to the even/odd frame selector?  Doing that would have made it possible to greatly improve the readability of text displays on long-persistence CRTs.